# Installing ECLIPSE CHE throw 150 errors

Tags: eclipse

**Installing CHE throw 150 errors**

Im creating a environment to test and play with the most stable version possible of che but already have another service on my machine using port 8080 then did it:

```
docker run -p 9000:8080 --name che --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v ~/.eclipseche:/data eclipse/che-server:latest
```

It throw a lot of errors as you can see [here](https://github.com/eclipse/che/files/3025165/che150Errors.txt).
I opened this issue [here](https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/13025).

The fisrt one you can read is "*Property CHE_HOST is not found as system property or environment variable.*" but there is no instruction on [che docs](https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/che-6/quick-start.html#docker) to set any variable, the point is its looks like an bug.

I see i can change the internal port with `-e CHE_PORT=9500` but dont know if its is related with it.

About my OS:

```
lsb_release -a
   No LSB modules are available.
   Distributor ID:  Ubuntu
   Description: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
   Release: 18.04
   Codename:    bionic
```

Comment: The very first message in the exception makes it very obvious. Please actually go read it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Question updated. There is a lot of other errors too, this one you told is telling to set an variable, the point its not documented, followed the che docs and still have problem, thanks.

Comment: I found it in the [docs](https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/che-6/docker-single-user.html).

Comment: @MichaelHampton "Server startup in 53839 ms
" its ok now, I think they need to warn about it on "Quick-Start" , it wasnt so quick to me, thanks for the help.